# Astronomic plate solving in Python (Astropy)

Tags: python, coordinates, camera-calibration, astronomy, astropy

I'm looking for several days now how to solve my problem.
I want to calibrate my CCD pictures (FITS files) so that I can generate the FITS headertopics to di astrometry ib them.
I have a number of stars of which I know RA and DEC and I want to use this data to calculate the parameters to calibrate my photo. I found a web page that does excact what I need but the source code is not online:
http://www1.phys.vt.edu/~jhs/SIP/astrometrycalc.html

In AstroPy coordinate and WCS I find all the functions that I need to do my job but they all assume a fully completed FITS header and I do not have one. (the photos come from an SLR camera in RAW format)

My question is whether I overlook a function or someone who can put me on the road to calculate the header parameters so that I can complete it with the necessary data?

Who can deliver me from my suffering.

tnx

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to plate-solve your image and write the coordinate information and possibly other details into the FITS header.

Have you considered using [Astrometry.net](http://nova.astrometry.net/api_help)? There is a python client [here](https://github.com/dstndstn/astrometry.net/blob/master/net/client/client.py).

You will need to convert your image from raw. Astrometry can handle [fits, jpg, gif, and png formats](http://nova.astrometry.net/upload).  You can then use Astropy to update the fits header with the results from the Astrometry API. Details on how to work with FITS headers can be found [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#working-with-fits-headers).

Comment: thanks for reply.

Well I certainly looked at Astrometry.net but the problem is that a lot of plates here contain big object (like the moon or comets) and little stars and they can't be solved automatically. Most of the time, the little amount of stars visible are well known (due to there big magnitude) so I can provide the coordinates of them manually but it seems I'll have to solve them manually too.

I convert my CR2 files to FITS with IRIS so my header is almost empty